# C# - IF with more string variables and OR operator

Tags: c#, if-statement

I would like to check if any variable is empty or null in other words I would like to check if all parameters are sent.
I have this code but it isn't working.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{regid}/{year}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string regid, int? year, string un, string ps)
{
    var isRegIDNumeric = int.TryParse(regid, out _);
    if (!isRegIDNumeric || year == null || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(un)) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ps)))
    {
     ...
    }
```

If I call like this, one parameter is missing, IF isn't working

```
localhost/test/?regid=001&year=2019&un=ws.test
```

I got this message:

```
<Error>
  <Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 
  'localhost/test/?regid=001&year=2019&un=ws.test'.
  </Message>
  <MessageDetail>No action was found on the controller 'test' that matches 
  the request.
  </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

If I call with all parameters everything is OK, whole procedure is executed.

```
localhost/test/?regid=001&year=2019&un=ws.test&ps=test
```

When I had only 2 variables ...

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{regid}/{year}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string regid, int? year)
{
    var isRegIDNumeric = int.TryParse(regid, out _);
    if (!isRegIDNumeric || year == null)
    {
     ...
    }
```

and called like this, one parameter is missing ...

```
localhost/test/?regid=001
```

Everything was OK, IF was regularly executed.

How to make functional IF with all 4 variables if any of them is null or empty?

Comment: You tell that the code is not working but you don't tell the input (of the case that fails) and the expected output in that case! The code seems correct so maybe your data is not what you think it is! Have you debugged it?

Comment: If I omit any of parameters the IF code should be executed. Now is working if I omit regno or year but if I omit un or ps IF code is not executed

Comment: Can you give specific values of un and ps that you think should cause the IF statement to be executed, but aren't. The code looks like it should work.

Comment: As written the question does contains required information for us to help you. The problem is probably not in the code that is shown. You need to show us how you call the function.

Comment: I added more examples. I would like to check if all parameters are sent.

Comment: how do you call the `Get` function?

Comment: I added above to code.

Answer (score 0):

In your 4 parameters example both string parameters are mandatory. That's why you get an error.
If you want them to be optional, assign them default value null. Than if statement would work.
Or add another Get() method.

Comment: All parameters are mandatory and I would like to execute IF if one of them is missing.

Comment: By optional I meant to send request without parameters and verify them in controller. Otherwise you have to check parameters before sending request or handle error message.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249019/web-api-optional-parameters) another question have the answer of yours and corroborates what [David Pivotar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4929015/david-pivovar) said.