# I am getting error "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Request URL:

`/api/Test/Retrieve/14012638/?14012647`

Endpoint:

```
[Route("Retrieve/{firstid}/{secondid?}")]       
public async Task<TestAPI> Retrieve(long firstid, long secondid)
```

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check the status of the response.  A good response should be 200 OK.  You must be getting something else and underlining code is not giving the exact error number.  The error number will help determine how to fix issue.

Comment: I guess you have api/test declared. Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249019/web-api-optional-parameters) help?

Comment: its not even hitting api

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769379/why-is-it-that-no-http-resource-was-found-that-matches-the-request-uri-here

Comment: Can you provide more code, please? Especially class attributes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to place your route at the controller level and your HTTP verb at the action level.

For your requirement, you can do this like below. I assume you are doing a `GET` operation.

```cs
[HttpGet("Retrieve/{firstid}/{secondid?}")]    
public async Task<WellsTradeAccountsInformation> Retrieve(long firstid, long secondid) { … }
```

If your controller' route is `api/Test`, then you can call this as:

```
GET /api/Test/Retrieve/14012638/14012647
```

or

```
GET /api/Test/Retrieve/14012638
```

As the second parameter is an optional value type, if you don't pass it will default to 0.

Comment: in some cases we dont need to pass second parameter and is optional.is there any way we can make this work for request type:/api/Test/Retrieve/14012638/?14012647

Comment: [HttpGet("Retrieve/{firstid}/{secondid?}")]    
public async Task<WellsTradeAccountsInformation> Retrieve(long firstid, long secondid)

Comment: @TestforAngular I could able to get the response properly with route which I mentioned in the answer, could you please share the route you are trying.

Comment: @TestforAngular as the second parameter mentioned as optional with '?' [HttpGet("Retrieve/{firstid}/{secondid?}")]  you can ignore the second parameter if you don't want to pass in route like this GET /api/Test/Retrieve/14012638'. I tried with fiddler and it is giving successful response for both api routes

Comment: GET /api/Test/Retrieve/14012638/?14012647 should work with [Route("Retrieve/{firstid}/{secondid?}")]       
public async Task<TestAPI> Retrieve(long firstid, long secondid = 0) Issue is secondid always set to zero even after passing value as second parameter.How can i rewrite the code to accept second value from API

Comment: I see you passing '?' in second parameter could you please remove and try.

Comment: yes that works but is there any way we can change in code rather than url?

Comment: This is my code [Route("Retrieve/{firstid}/{secondid?}")] public async Task<TestAPI> Retrieve(long firstid, long secondid = 0)

Comment: Actually when u call GET /api/Test/Retrieve/14012638/?14012647 it will not consider the second parameter as long type since you are passing ? in it. Why you are passing ? in the parameter any specific requirement? Could you please eloborate if any.

Comment: its the ui team who want to pass paramter like this so can anything can be done on controller side

Comment: If u want the parameter to accept with ? Mark change the second parameter to string instead of long.

Comment: If u want the parameter to accept with ? Mark change the second parameter to string instead of long. I have very limited knowledge on your requirement but the best practice would be to send second parameter only if required as it is optional, and if passing the second parameter then pass it in proper format of the type your api expecting.