# Swagger - required mark missing for string data type query parameter in .NET core API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, swagger, query-string

I m trying to make query parameter as required in API, but the swagger doesnt pick this as required. but the other data type has no issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share more code? Besides, it's better to provide code rather than picture so that we can reproduce your problem.If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Comment: Do you have nullable reference types disabled or are you working with an older .NET version (under .NET 6)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38249991/7389293 Parameters with defaul value are marked as "not required". So, if you want any field to be required, just don't provide default values to it.

Answer (score 0):

I do the code like you , and the swagger pick this as required.

[image]

And I am curious why your serviceId is string path.