# Multiple optional parameters with in-between empty parameters in Web API attribute routing

Tags: c#, url-routing, webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

This is in .NET 6

The Action method:

```
[HttpGet("GetCustomers/{customerName?}/{customerNumber?}/{customerSignature?}")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetCustomers(string customerName = null, string customerNumber = null, string customerSignature = null)
{
```

This url hits the method:

*https://localhost:44378/api/Customer/GetCustomers/A/B/C*

But below url doesn't hit the method:

*https://localhost:44378/api/Customer/GetCustomers/A//C*

Any solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web API optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249019/web-api-optional-parameters)